# How to implement to display estimated delivery date on product Page in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page, delivery-date

In magento, how to setup Expected Delivery date option in the product page itself. Choosing this date(Expected Delivery) and then add the product to cart.

Comment: You can add the expected delivery date as an attribute. Create a custom attribute of type date.

Comment: @MGento, I alrady added attribute as name delivery_date and also Catalog Input Type for Store Owner is "Date".but not getting field on backend where as added it.

Comment: Have you added the attribute to an attribute set?

Comment: @jscar,I also added attribute set.but it seems not shows on product page.I want to display on this.which is user select date and also checkout section too.

Comment: @AnikeshShahi just to clarify. You can see it in the backend on the product configuration but not on the frontend on the product page? Did you select Yes in the attribute configuration for "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"

Comment: Yes, I h've selected option to visibile on product View page on frontend from backend during makes attributes.

Comment: Usually, these newly created attributes comes under the More Information tab, on the product details page. Also make sure, you have cleared the cache.

Comment: @MGento,Thanks a lot,able to access this field on additional tab on product page.it is silly mistake from my side.thnks

Comment: You are welcome :)  Have a great day